Congruent diagonalization using row and column operations

Let $$A=\begin{pmatrix} 
1 & 2 & 3\\
2 & 4 & 6\\
3 & 6 & 9 \end{pmatrix}.$$
Find an invertible matrix $P$ such that $P^tAP$ is diagonal.

Let me start by saying that I already obtained the matrix $P$ using one particular method: I obtained a basis of eigenvectors of $A$ and applied Gram-Schmidt (and normalized) in order to obtain an orthonormal basis. The vectors of this orthonormal basis are clearly the columns of $P$. In fact, eventually I obtained, $$P^tAP=\begin{pmatrix} 14 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}.$$
Now, I want to solve this exercise using a different method: Using row and column operations.
Following the Algorithm 12.1, so far I have: $$\begin{pmatrix} 
1 & 2 & 3 & \bigm| & 1 & 0 & 0\\
2 & 4 & 6 & \bigm| & 0 & 1 & 0\\
3 & 6 & 9 & \bigm| & 0 & 0 & 1  
\end{pmatrix} \overset{R_2: -2R_1+R_2}{\longrightarrow} $$
$$\begin{pmatrix} 
1 & 2 & 3 & \bigm| & 1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & \bigm| & -2 & 1 & 0\\
3 & 6 & 9 & \bigm| & 0 & 0 & 1  
\end{pmatrix}\overset{C_2: -2C_1+C_2}{\longrightarrow}$$
$$\begin{pmatrix} 
1 & 0 & 3 & \bigm| & 1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & \bigm| & -2 & 1 & 0\\
3 & 0 & 9 & \bigm| & 0 & 0 & 1  
\end{pmatrix}\overset{R_3: -3R_1+R_3}{\longrightarrow}$$
$$\begin{pmatrix} 
1 & 0 & 3 & \bigm| & 1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & \bigm| & -2 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & \bigm| & -3 & 0 & 1  
\end{pmatrix}\overset{C_3: -3C_1+C_3}{\longrightarrow}$$
$$\begin{pmatrix} 
1 & 0 & 0 & \bigm| & 1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & \bigm| & -2 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & \bigm| & -3 & 0 & 1  
\end{pmatrix}.$$
This is what I have so far, but I don't know how to proceed after this step. I don't see which step from the algorithm I should apply next. I think the algorithm doesn't even consider this case I've arrived to. Any help is welcome
Note: The image of the Algorithm 12.1 was taken from Schaum's Outline: Linear Algebra, 6th Edition by Lipschutz, page $363-364$

I think the algorithm doesn't even consider this case I've arrived to. Why not? The matrix is not invertible, so there is no inverse. You want an invertible $P$ instead with $P^TAP={\rm diag}(1,0,0)$.

@DietrichBurde Shouldn't it be $P^TAP=diag(14,0,0)$? Or any combination of $0,0,14$ in the diagonal entries since these are the eigenvalues of $A$?

Be careful, $PAP^T$ is not similar to $A$ in general (but $PAP^{-1}$ is). So the eigenvalues are different. Anyway, the diagonal $(1,0,0)$ is a multiple of $(14,0,0)$.

The algorithm gives you the desired matrix $P$. Note that
$$
\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 \cr -2 & 1 & 0 \cr -3 & 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix} \cdot A\cdot  \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 \cr -2 & 1 & 0 \cr -3 & 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}^T=
\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 \cr 0 & 0 & 0 \cr 0 & 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix},
$$
as required.

Ah ok I see now. I was worried because I tried multiple times and always got $diag(1,0,0)$ on the left side and never  $diag(14,0,0)$. But I see that's not required now. Anyway, I got $P^TAP=diag(14,0,0)$ using Gram-Schmidt. Thanks for your help.

Here is how it works out when keeping track of the matrix $P$  in $P^T HP = D$
$$  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc     \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc $$
$$ P^T H P = D  $$
$$\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
 - 2 & 1 & 0 \\ 
 - 3 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 2 & 3 \\ 
2 & 4 & 6 \\ 
3 & 6 & 9 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 &  - 2 &  - 3 \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
 = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$
$$  $$
$$ Q^T D Q = H  $$
$$\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
2 & 1 & 0 \\ 
3 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 2 & 3 \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
 = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 2 & 3 \\ 
2 & 4 & 6 \\ 
3 & 6 & 9 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$
$$  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc     \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc $$
Full details
Algorithm discussed at reference for linear algebra books that teach reverse Hermite method for symmetric matrices
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester%27s_law_of_inertia
$$ H = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 2 & 3 \\ 
2 & 4 & 6 \\ 
3 & 6 & 9 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$
$$  D_0 = H  $$
$$ E_j^T D_{j-1} E_j = D_j  $$
$$  P_{j-1} E_j = P_j  $$
$$ E_j^{-1} Q_{j-1}  = Q_j  $$
$$  P_j Q_j = Q_j P_j = I  $$
$$ P_j^T H P_j = D_j  $$
$$ Q_j^T D_j Q_j = H  $$
$$ H = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 2 & 3 \\ 
2 & 4 & 6 \\ 
3 & 6 & 9 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$
==============================================
$$ E_{1} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 &  - 2 & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$
$$  P_{1} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 &  - 2 & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
, \; \; \; Q_{1} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 2 & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
, \; \; \; D_{1} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 0 & 3 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
3 & 0 & 9 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$
==============================================
$$ E_{2} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 0 &  - 3 \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$
$$  P_{2} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 &  - 2 &  - 3 \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
, \; \; \; Q_{2} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 2 & 3 \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
, \; \; \; D_{2} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$
==============================================
$$  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc     \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc $$
$$ P^T H P = D  $$
$$\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
 - 2 & 1 & 0 \\ 
 - 3 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 2 & 3 \\ 
2 & 4 & 6 \\ 
3 & 6 & 9 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 &  - 2 &  - 3 \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
 = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$
$$  $$
$$ Q^T D Q = H  $$
$$\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
2 & 1 & 0 \\ 
3 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 2 & 3 \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
 = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 2 & 3 \\ 
2 & 4 & 6 \\ 
3 & 6 & 9 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$
$$  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc     \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc $$
