Verify that a quadratic form is NOT positive definite
Verify that the quadratic form $$q(x_1,x_2,x_3)=x_1^2+4x_1x_2+3x_2^2+2x_2x_3+6x_3^2$$  is NOT positive definite and find a vector in $v\in\mathbb{R}^3$ such that $q(v)<0$ .

I have made several attempts at diagonalizing it, but  I did not have any success.
The first thing I did was finding the matrix associated to the quadratic form, which is:
$$A=\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 2 & 0\\
2 & 3 & 1\\
0 & 1 & 6
\end{pmatrix}.$$
After obtaining this matrix, I tried to build an orthonormal basis such that the vectors of this orthonormal basis would be the columns of a matrix $P$ such that $P^TAP=D$. I abandoned this idea because the eigenvalues of $A$ are horrible to write in exact form (they take a lot of characters to write in exact form).
The second approach I took was applying an algorithm of row and column operations. Eventually, I got that $$P^TAP= \begin{pmatrix} 
1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & -1 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 7          
\end{pmatrix},$$ where $$P=\begin{pmatrix}
1 & -2 & 2\\
0 & 1 & -1\\
0 & 0 & -1
\end{pmatrix}.$$ But this doesn't give me the diagonalization of $q$.
After these failed attempts, I tried to diagonalize it without using matrices. So I found the following website, which discusses Lagrange´s method, but I couldn't follow the method successfully.
Any help is extremly appreciated as I have been struggling with this exercise the whole day

Why don't you compute the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of A? Then you can use Gram-Schmidt orthogonalization to get $P$.

@fusheng I tried that, but if you check the eigenvectors of $A$, you will see that they  have too many characters and normalizing them would be a long process

^"you will see that they have too many characters"? what do you mean by characters? In order to check the definiteness of a matrix, its eigenvalues can be used as has been pointed by @fusheng.

Are you allowed to use computer?

@CroCo In order to gain insight about the problem? Yes. In order to provide a solution? No, everything must be done manually.

@user926356 is $P^T=P^{-1}$? What is $D$ here? eigenvalues and eigenvectors?

@CroCo In the first attempt $D$ was supposed to be the diagonal matrix with eigenvalues of $A$ on the diagonal, and the columns of $P$ would be normalized eigenvectors of $A$ (since they were already orthogonal). But on the second method $D$ is not a diagonal matrix with eigenvalues.

Your second approach provides a solution: in view of the second column of $P^TAP$, the second column $v$ of $P$ should satisfy $q(v)=-1$.
Let us check:
$$q(-2,1,0)=(-2)^2+4(-2)1+3\cdot1^2+2\cdot1\cdot0+6\cdot0^2=-1.$$
This could also be found more directly:
$$q(x_1,x_2,x_3)=(x_1+2x_2)^2-x_2^2+2x_2x_3+6x_3^2=-1$$
as soon as
$$x_1+2x_2=0,\quad x_2=1,\quad x_3=0.$$

Remark.
Note that (though unnecessarily) this first step of Lagrange's method could be continued:
$$q(x_1,x_2,x_3)=y_1^2-y_2^2+7y_3^2$$
where
$$y_1=x_1+2x_2,\quad y_2=x_2-x_3,\quad y_3=x_3,$$
which is equivalent to
$$\begin{pmatrix}x_1\\x_2\\x_3\end{pmatrix}=Q\begin{pmatrix}y_1\\y_2\\y_3\end{pmatrix},\quad Q:=\begin{pmatrix}1&-2&-2\\0&1&1\\0&0&1\end{pmatrix},$$
$$Q^TAQ=\begin{pmatrix}1&0&0\\0&-1&0\\0&0&7\end{pmatrix}.$$
We thus recover (a slight variant of) your second approach.

You are correct $P^TAP$ is symmetric, I made a typo and typed $9$ instead of $0$. I have corrected the typo

In order to get the first summand to be $(x_1+2x_2)^2$ you first wrote $3x_2^2$ as $4x_2^2-x_2^2$, right? Or how did you do it?

Right. Or more precisely, the other way round: this first summand came (following Lagrange's algorithm) from completing $x_1^2+4x_1x_2$ to make a square, so I had to add and subtract $4x_2^2$.

Ah, I see. Thanks!

Are $\lambda_{1,2,3} = 1,-1,7$ the eigenvalues?

@CroCo No, those are not the eigenvalues. But you can apply the following algorithm to $A$ to obtain $P^TAP=diag(1,-1,7)$. See the algorithm: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4936956/congruent-diagonalization-using-row-and-column-operations/4937229#4937229

@user926356 No need of a more complicated algorithm: Lagrange's one did it.

Inspired by Sylvester's criterion, let's look at the upper-left submatrix $\begin{bmatrix}1 & 2 \\ 2 & 3 \end{bmatrix}$. It already has a negative determinant. We are also lucky that $\begin{bmatrix}x_1 & x_2 & 0 \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}1 & 2 & 0 \\ 2 & 3 & 1\\ 0 & 1 & 6\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}x_1 \\ x_2 \\ 0\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}x_1 & x_2 \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 2 \\ 2 & 3 \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}x_1 \\ x_2\end{bmatrix}$ so it suffices to focus on this smaller subproblem.
You can diagonalize this $2 \times 2$ matrix and find an eigenvector for the negative eigenvalue. Alternatively, we can guess that there is a solution with $x_1 \ne 0$, so we can assume WLOG that $x_1 = 1$. Then the quadratic form reduces to $1 + 4x_2 + 3x_2^2$, for which $x_2=-2/3$ yields a negative value. So $v=\begin{bmatrix}1 \\ -2/3 \\ 0\end{bmatrix}$ is a solution to the original question.

Very easy to follow, thanks!

We may be overreading this.

When you form the symmetric matrix, the determinant is easily proved negative ($-7$). You can't have a positive (semi)definite quadratic form when this holds.

We also find that the $(3,3)$ principal minir of this natrix is also negative ($-1$), so there are vectors with $x_3=0$ such that the quadratic form is negative. We then see that this holds when $x_1^2+4x_1x_2+3x_2^2=(x_1+2x_2)(x_1+2x_2)-x_2^2<0$ and can pick $x_1$ and $x_2$ accordingly.



One way to check a matrix's definiteness is by checking its eigenvalues. If you don't want to explicity find them, you can rely on this fact
$$
\prod_{i=1}^3 \lambda_i = \det(A) = -7.
$$
With three eigenvalues and a negative determinant, at least one must be negative.

Assume you can get the eigenvalues and eigenvectors. Let $A\in\mathbb{R}^{3\times 3}$ and $A=A^T$. Any symmetric matrix is orthogonally diagonalizable and its eigenvalues are real. Let $x\in\mathbb{R}^3$, the quadratic form $f(x) = x^TAx $ is positive definite if and only if $f(x)>0$ for all $x\neq 0$. We know $A=PDP^T$ where $D$ a diagonal matrix whose diagonal elements are the eigenvalues of A. Let $y\in\mathbb{R}^3$ and $x=Py$ where $P$ is an invertible matrix whose columns are the eigenvectors of $A$; therefore, we get
$$
\begin{align}
f(y) = x^TAx &= (Py)^TA(Py) \\
&= y^TP^TAPy \\
&= y^T Dy \\
&= y^T \begin{bmatrix} \lambda_1& 0 & 0 \\ 0& \lambda_2&0 \\ 0 &0&\lambda_n\end{bmatrix}y \\
&= \lambda_1y^2_1+\lambda_2y^2_2+\lambda_3 y^2_3.
\end{align}
$$
The function $f(y)>0$ for all $y\neq 0$ is completely determined by the signs of the eigenvalues. From the above note, at least one eigenvalue is negative. Choose any $y_1,y_2,y_3$ such that $f(y)<0$ and then find $x$ (i.e. $x=Py$).
